# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name pan_number.(panValidation)

Tags: codeigniter, callback, hmvc

I am using HMVC in Code Igniter 3.0.4
I have googled and tried to fix this problem by doing following things.

1> Auto loaded security

2> Using xss_clean

3> In application/language/english put the file : MY_form_validation_lang.php with error messages

4> in application/libraries/MY_form_validation.php put following code :

```
public $CI;
public function __construct($rules = array()) {
    parent::__construct($rules);
    $this->CI->lang->load('MY_form_validation');
}

function run($module = '', $group = '') {
    (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
    return parent::run($group);
}
```

5> added custom error in application/language/english/MY_Form_validation_lang file :

```
$lang['panValidation'] = 'Invalid PAN Number system file';
```

Here is the final code (controller):

```
<?php
class Personal_details extends MX_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        no_cache();

        /* use xss clean */
        $this->load->helper('security');

        /* form and inputs */
        $this->load->helper('form');

        /* form validations */
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    /* CUSTOM CHECK CONSTRAINT FOR FORM INPUT */

    public function panValidation($panNumber) {
        $pan_regex = "/^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}$/";
        if (!preg_match($pan_regex, $panNumber)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('panValidation', 'Invalid PAN Number');
            return false; // invalid pan
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

     public function index() {
        if ($this->input->post()):
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pan_number', 'pan_number', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|callback_panValidation');           

            if ($this->form_validation->run($this) === FALSE) {
                /*$this->form_validation->set_message('panValidation', 'The {field} value is invalid');*/
                echo validation_errors();
            } else {
                echo 'No error';
            }
        endif;
        $this->load->view('pan/index', $this->data);
    }
}
?>
```

And still the error is coming. Dont know whats going on. Please help. 
I am using shared host on linux, and file name is MY_form_validation_lang.php but locally its MY_Form_validation_lang.php (difference is capital f)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the next file name: form_validation_lang.php for your custom language file. Don't you use 'MY_' prefix for it.
(e.g.: application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php)
see details:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html

Comment: Hi Zaragoli, thanks, I tried the solution you told me, but it still shows same error.